# re-triggering css animations with react

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations

I have a list of items in a table.  I would like an item's row to briefly flash with a highlight due to some external events.

I have a CSS animation `fadingHighlight` to accomplish the desired visual effect, and when an event comes in I set a class `last-updated` on the desired row to trigger the animation.

However, when an update comes in for the same row multiple times in a row, only the first update causes a flash. (I believe this is because react persists the `last-updated` class on the row rather than re-rendering it, and thus the css doesn't re-start the animation.)

How can I re-trigger the animation if the same item gets updates multiple times in a row?

Demo and code: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-lamarr-d71zh?file=/src/App.js

Relevant portions of the react:

```
const Item = ({ id, isLastUpdated }) => (
  <div className={isLastUpdated ? "last-updated" : ""}>Item {id}</div>
);

const App = () => {
  const [lastUpdatedId, setLastUpdatedId] = React.useState(undefined);

  const itemIds = ["1", "2", "3"];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>The list of items</h2>
      {itemIds.map((id) => (
        <Item key={id} id={id} isLastUpdated={lastUpdatedId === id} />
      ))}

      <h2>Trigger updates</h2>
      {itemIds.map((id) => (
        <button onClick={() => setLastUpdatedId(id)}>Update item {id}</button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Styles:

```
@keyframes fadingHighlight {
  0% {
    background-color: #ff0;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
}

.last-updated {
  animation: fadingHighlight 2s;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Thanks again to [@leo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8274308/leo) for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70525758/16054213) which helped me get to this one!)

I got the desired behavior (forcing the animation to restart) by

1. Immediately **removing** the highlight class, and
2. Setting a timeout (10msec seems to be fine) for adding back the highlight class.

The timeout seems to force react to separately render the component without the highlight class and then again with the highlight class, causing the animation to restart. (Without the timeout, react may collapse these changes into one render step, causing the DOM to treat the whole thing as a no-op.)

A nice result of this approach where each `Item` manages its own highlight state is that multiple items can be highlighted at the same time (e.g. if updates for one item come in before the highlight fades on another).

[Demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-frog-by9ht?file=/src/App.js)

```
const Item = ({ id, updateTime }) => {
  const [showHighlight, setShowHighlight] = React.useState(false);

  // By putting `updateTime` in the dependency array of `useEffect,
  // we re-trigger the highlight every time `updateTime` changes.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (updateTime) {
      setShowHighlight(false);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setShowHighlight(true);
      }, 10);
    }
  }, [updateTime]);

  return <div className={showHighlight ? "updated" : ""}>Item {id}</div>;
};

const App = () => {
  // tracking the update times at the top level
  const [updateTimes, setUpdateTimes] = React.useState({});

  // ...
        <Item key={id} id={id} updateTime={updateTimes[id]} />

  // ...
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setUpdateTimes({ ...updateTimes, [id]: Date.now() });
          }}
        >
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here we are fighting against the React principle of *don't update things that don't change*, and I've never done something like this but, it seems to solve your problem.

Due to the react behavior of waiting to the code to run, to then compare the results with the current values, this will not work:

```js
// Let suppose it is currently `1`.

setLastUpdatedId(undefined); // <-- it does not apply.
setLastUpdatedId(1);         // <-- it does not trigger any changes.
```

Solution (sort of):

I used `useEffect` and an auxiliar state (`waitAndHold`) to play with the asynchronous behavior of `useState` & `useEffect` instead of just setting the new value in-line with `setLastUpdatedId`. So we can reset to `undefined`, wait for the changes to apply, and then reset again to the same value as before.

**Working solution [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-lake-ibssx?file=/src/App.js)**.

What's new in the `App`:

```
const [waitAndHoldId, setWaitAndHoldId] = React.useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  setLastUpdatedId(waitAndHoldId[0]);
}, [waitAndHoldId]);

function resetLastUpdatedId(id) {
  if (lastUpdatedId !== id) {
    // If it's different: just set it and we are done.
    setLastUpdatedId(id);
  } else {
    // If not:
    setWaitAndHoldId([id]);

    /**
     * Setting an array will always trigger the useEffect (even if
     * it remains the same). The useEffect will take an instant to
     * run. Meanwhile, force the `lastUpdatedId` to reset with a
     * different value (e.g.: undefined).
     */

    // This will run before the useEffect.
    setLastUpdatedId(undefined);
  }
}

// ...

<button onClick={() => resetLastUpdatedId(id)}>
  Update item {id}
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

This solution works but I got some feedback from a teammate that `set...` functions generally shouldn't be called in the rendering loop and instead should go in a `useEffect`. When I made that change the demo still worked, but in our production code it didn't.

My guess is that relying on multiple `useEffect` leads to some sensitivity to react's event loop internals as to the sequence of those effect calls and when they are collapsed into a single rendering step.

Dodging that problem led to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70552001/16054213) (which also involves less code.)

**Original answer**

[Leo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70513731/16054213) (and in particular the use of `useEffect`) works!  And it led me to a revised updated solution ([demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-cherry-9c3s0?file=/src/App.js)) that has some desirable properties.

The main change from Leo's answer is that each `Item` component is now responsible for independently managing the state for the highlighting effect, and it needs to be passed the time of the most recent update.  (Or, more precisely, it needs to be passed some new value on each update, but the time seems the most natural.)

A nice result of this approach is that multiple items can be highlighted at the same time (e.g. if updates for one item come in before the highlight fades on another).

```
const Item = ({ id, updateTime }) => {
  const [lastUpdateTime, setLastUpdateTime] = React.useState(undefined);
  const [showHighlight, setShowHighlight] = React.useState(false);
  const [triggerHighlight, setTriggerHighlight] = React.useState(false);

  if (updateTime && updateTime !== lastUpdateTime) {
    // Update time has changed! 
    setLastUpdateTime(updateTime);
    // Remove the highlighting class so that re-adding
    // it restarts the animation.
    setShowHighlight(false);
    // And record that we need to re-add the class (but don't do it yet).
    setTriggerHighlight(true);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (triggerHighlight) {
      // Re-add the highlight class inside useEffect so 
      // that it will happen in a separate render step.
      setShowHighlight(true);
      setTriggerHighlight(false);
    }
  }, [triggerHighlight]);

  return <div className={showHighlight ? "updated" : ""}>Item {id}</div>;
};
```

And we need App-level state to track those most recent update times:

```
  const [updateTimes, setUpdateTimes] = React.useState({});

  // ...

        <Item key={id} id={id} updateTime={updateTimes[id]} />

  // ...
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setUpdateTimes({ ...updateTimes, [id]: Date.now() });
          }}
        >

   // ...
```

Comment: I absolutely agree in making each element responsible for its own behavior, it's a more elegant solution. I'm glad it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same problem trying to restart a CSS animation in React.

I will caution you very strongly against relying on a timeout to distinguish when your re-renders will trigger. What works correctly on one computer, may behave very differently on another one. Some of the worst bugs I've chased in my career have been caused by assumptions on timing. They are the worst.

But anyways, I created a little util which queues state updates to gain this behavior without having to rely on timeouts.

```
// utils/useQueuedState.ts
import * as React from 'react'

export type QueuedState<T> = [state: T, setState: (state: T) => void]

export const useQueuedState = <T>(initialValue: T): QueuedState<T> => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState<T>(initialValue)
  const queue = React.useRef<T[]>([])

  const addToQueue = (newValue: T): void => {
    const valueMatchesState = queue.current.length === 0 && newValue === state
    const valueMatchesQueue =
      queue.current.length > 0 && queue.current[queue.current.length - 1] === newValue
    const valueIsDupe = valueMatchesQueue || valueMatchesState

    if (!valueIsDupe) {
      queue.current.push(newValue)
    }

    if (queue.current.length === 1) {
      setState(newValue)
    }
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (queue.current.length > 0 && queue.current[queue.current.length - 1]) {
      queue.current.shift()

      if (queue.current.length > 0) {
        setState(queue.current[0])
      }
    }
  }, [state])

  return [state, addToQueue]
}
```

And you would use it like this:

```
// yourApp.tsx
export const App = () => {
  const [lastUpdatedId, setLastUpdatedId] = useQueuedState<string | undefined>(undefined);

  const itemIds = ["1", "2", "3"];
  const onClick = React.useCallback((id: string) => {
    setLastUpdatedId(undefined);
    setLastUpdatedId(id);
  },[])
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>The list of items</h2>
      {itemIds.map((id) => (
        <Item key={id} id={id} isLastUpdated={lastUpdatedId === id} />
      ))}

      <h2>Trigger updates</h2>
      {itemIds.map((id) => (
        <button onClick={() => setLastUpdatedId(id)}>Update item {id}</button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The benefit here is that the app will first set the `lastUpdatedId` to `undefined` and then after that value has been set, it will only then trigger a new call to `setState` with the new state. This causes the animation to restart without having to rely on timeouts.

Important notes:
In my case, I didn't need to handle initializer functions or updater functions in `useState`. You would need to update accordingly if your use-case required that behavior.

I also never replace existing queued values with new values. Only push on top of the queue. You would need to update accordingly if you wanted to do something like limit the queue to only 2 values.